# Autofill billing Information on checkout page in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

I need to autofill the billing information on checkout with Drupal commerce.

I added to drupal user a field called 'field_commerce_billing' like a reference to 'Customer profile' entity and I want to autofill the checkout with the customer profile fields values if an user is logged in.

Comment: now you can use: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook this module does it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works for me.

```php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  global $user;

  if ($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout' && $user->uid) {
    $user = user_load($user->uid);
    $loaded_billing = commerce_customer_profile_load($user->field_commerce['und'][0]['profile_id']);
    
    // For each field in customer profile, fill the form field with the $user value.
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address'] = $loaded_billing->commerce_customer_address['und'][0];
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_telephone_number']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $loaded_billing->field_telephone_number['und'][0]['value'];
  } 
}
```

I tried to retrieve the *commerce_customer_profile* field list, but I didn't find a way to generalize an action for filling every field type in the form.

Comment: @Molot mind explaining what you mean here?

Comment: @MrUpsidown The comment was for a suggested edit that made drastic changes in the code shown in this answer.