# Autofill billing information on checkout page

Tags: ajax, commerce

I have placed billing information in the checkout pane. I want to autofill the billing information. There is a similar question in stackexchange [Autofill billing Information on checkout page in Drupal Commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97572/autofill-billing-information-on-checkout-page-in-drupal-commerce). But this is not working for me. This is the code they mentioned

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  global $user;

  if( $form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout' && $user->uid ){
    $user = user_load( $user->uid );
    $loaded_billing = commerce_customer_profile_load($user->field_commerce['und'][0]['profile_id']);

    // For each field in customer profile I fill the form field with the $user value 
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']  = $loaded_billing->commerce_customer_address['und'][0];
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_telephone_number']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value']  = $loaded_billing->field_telephone_number['und'][0]['value'];
  } 
}
```

But I don't have `commerce_customer_profile_load($user->field_commerce['und'][0]['profile_id']);` . Is there any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Commerce Addressbook](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook)** module which provides solution for your problem. It is already mentioned in the [same question](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook) as a comment.

More details about this module (from its project page):

> Commerce Addressbook is a module that allows authenticated customers
>   to reuse previously entered addresses during checkout. They can manage
>   all entered addresses in their user panel (user/%user/addressbook).
>
> Note that for data consistency reasons editing a previously entered
>   address won't change it on previously made orders.